# The [underscore] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) is defined as:

> The underscore, Unicode Character 'LOW LINE' (U+005F). For questions about Underscore.js, please use the `underscore.js` tag.

Is that really a useful tag? At all? I looked at the questions tagged with it and they were all supposed to be tagged [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js) instead. At this point [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) only seems to add to the confusion with no real benefit.

Should the two be merged together, and just drop the silly "low line" character tag?

Edit: Yes, there is a related question from half a year ago, but the problem has manifested itself yet again. I *really* think this is a clear indication that something more permanent should be done to fix this.

Comment: `I looked at the questions tagged with it and they were all supposed to be tagged underscore.js instead` -- Not quite.  There are at least a handful that discuss the underscore character specifically.

Comment: But not the majority by any stretch; besides do we really need a tag this specific, especially when it conflicts with a well known technology name? Who would subscribe to it?

Comment: While I don't think we need a tag for every possible punctuation mark, underscores do have special significance in programming.

Comment: It might be useful to change [underscore] to [underscores]; I think that might provide a hint to users that we're not talking about the library.

Comment: That sounds like something that would help, sure! My main issue is that it's so easy to confuse the two, I mean I didn't even know until just now that there were tags for specific punctuation characters (yes, there's also caret and star and so on, I checked..)

Comment: Or since there is a [double-underscore] tag, you could also rename it [single-underscore] :-) or more seriously maybe [underscore-character]? That would be similar to [null-character] for example.

Comment: Well, of the 92 questions that had the [underscore] tag, 62 were actually about underscores. :/  I should've made *you* fix them. :P

Comment: Might be better to have underscore as underscore-character, rather than underscores. Should tags be pluralised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed: retagged questions having to do with [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) to [underscores](/questions/tagged/underscores), and synonymized [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) to [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js)

Comment: The irony is I never once made a post about the underscore character or about underscore.js, was just my OCD kicking in. Thanks!